# Need help reading maillog with a deleted account on it

Tags: linux, email

I have a few general questions.  I have Googled these to no avail, either that of tutorials or blogs.

All have to do with the maillog.  About the same time ever day our site bogs down.  At this point we are looking into a possible email hijacking.

I have 2 accounts that seem to stand out. One mentioned here is only for internal use and is never logged into and nothing is ever sent from it. EVER.  However if I am reading this log correctly it looks as if it is being used.  Our mail rating has dropped to a "poor" status.

Yesterday I went into my ispconfig for my server and deleted the email address however todays log still shows it doing stuff.  Not sure where to go from here.

the from keeps dropping the email contestwinner@myserver.com

```
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 189042213CB4: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1590, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 1423C2213B83: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=983, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 158E72213BDA: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1590, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 178621E40029: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1159, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 17E442213D1D: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1539, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: BEB7A2213CA9: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1491, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: B989C1E4002A: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=2112, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: B4E252213CFC: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=868, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: BBDC12213C6F: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1444, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: BB87C1E4005E: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1558, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: C2FF92213BDC: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1476, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: C25832213D2F: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1483, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: C27CA2213A84: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1446, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: C45E02213CF3: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1444, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: C57712213B52: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1588, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: CBB4C2213D2A: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1190, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 45E1D2213B75: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=952, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 4A7641E40036: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1404, nrcpt=16 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 43EB62213CEF: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=947, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 4FDD02213C07: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1457, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 4898C2213D2C: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=940, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 4847B2213CAC: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1521, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 44E2C2213CD9: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=936, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 47BDC1E400A7: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1495, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 7B9112213CF4: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1539, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 773272213C6C: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1458, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 719831E4007C: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=946, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 7E9B31E4006A: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=951, nrcpt=16 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 7FBDF1E4000B: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1511, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 7B8251E40041: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1512, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 716921E40074: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1421, nrcpt=16 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 704EF2213B16: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1489, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: 2A8A01E400A3: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=930, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:10 mail postfix/qmgr[12626]: EAD441E40079: from=<contestwinner@myserver.com>, size=1438, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12650]: connect to london.com[204.74.99.100]: Connection refused (port 25)
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12637]: connect to SDVSD.COM[69.43.161.181]: Connection refused (port 25)
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12641]: connect to kasan.com[176.74.176.178]: Connection refused (port 25)
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12634]: certificate verification failed for mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com: num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12634]: certificate verification failed for mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com: num=24:invalid CA certificate
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12634]: certificate verification failed for mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com: num=26:unsupported certificate purpose
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12634]: certificate verification failed for mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com: num=10:certificate has expired
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12634]: certificate verification failed for mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com:certificate has expired
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12634]: certificate verification failed for mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com:certificate has expired
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12634]: certificate verification failed for mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com: num=10:certificate has expired
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12634]: certificate verification failed for mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com:certificate has expired
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12634]: certificate verification failed for mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com:certificate has expired
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12654]: connect to carmail.com[176.74.176.178]: Connection refused (port 25)
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12632]: connect to ymail.net[222.231.2.126]: Connection refused (port 25)
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12691]: connect to synpatico.ca[216.40.47.17]: Connection refused (port 25)
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12674]: connect to lives.ca[176.74.176.178]: Connection refused (port 25)
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12708]: connect to aliveandkicking.com[72.13.32.43]: No route to host (port 25)
Nov 18 23:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[12705]: 7FBDF1E4000B: host gateway-f2.isp.att.net[207.115.11.16] refused to talk to me: 550-66.194.252.172 blocked by ldap:ou=rblmx,dc=att,dc=net 550 Error - Blocked for abuse. See http://att.net/blocks
Nov 18 23:59:12 mail postfix/smtp[12645]: 189042213CB4: host mx1.free.fr[212.27.48.7] said: 451 too many errors from your ip (66.194.252.172), please visit http://postmaster.free.fr/ (in reply to DATA command)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12650]: 1423C2213B83: to=<gharbaoui@london.com>, relay=none, delay=88004, delays=88004/0.21/0.13/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to london.com[204.74.99.100]: Connection refused)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12654]: 17E442213D1D: to=<mahilive@carmail.com>, relay=none, delay=253333, delays=253332/0.24/0.29/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to carmail.com[176.74.176.178]: Connection refused)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12709]: 704EF2213B16: to=<ben.mcginty@talktalk.net>, relay=mx-c1.talktalk.net[62.24.202.3]:25, delay=93668, delays=93666/0.68/0.5/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mx-c1.talktalk.net[62.24.202.3] while receiving the initial server greeting)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12670]: C27CA2213A84: to=<ash187@tiscali.co.uk>, relay=mxgb1.opaltelecom.net[62.24.139.61]:25, delay=94943, delays=94942/0.38/1.1/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mxgb1.opaltelecom.net[62.24.139.61] refused to talk to me: 554-public.mx8gb1.int.opaltelecom.net 554 Your access to this mail system has been rejected due to the sending MTA's poor reputation. If you believe that this failure is in error, please contact the intended recipient via alternate means.)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12645]: 189042213CB4: to=<fabien.bellande@worldonline.fr>, relay=mx1.free.fr[212.27.48.6]:25, delay=67345, delays=67343/0.18/1.4/0.28, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mx1.free.fr[212.27.48.6] said: 451 too many errors from your ip (66.194.252.172), please visit http://postmaster.free.fr/ (in reply to DATA command))
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12634]: 93CC72213CA8: to=<llme12@excite.com>, relay=mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com[208.89.132.27]:25, delay=365988, delays=365986/0.09/0.51/2.3, dsn=4.1.1, status=deferred (host mail-in-excite.roc2.bluetie.com[208.89.132.27] said: 452 4.1.1 <llme12@excite.com> Account temporarily unavailable. Try again later (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12632]: 9FBEF1E4003A: to=<zak.page@ymail.net>, relay=none, delay=357659, delays=357658/0.07/0.65/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to ymail.net[222.231.2.126]: Connection refused)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12702]: 719831E4007C: to=<n@fcff.com>, relay=fcff.com[98.124.198.1]:25, delay=329381, delays=329380/0.64/0.2/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with fcff.com[98.124.198.1] while receiving the initial server greeting)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12637]: 926952213BDE: to=<SDFDS@SDVSD.COM>, relay=none, delay=432389, delays=432389/0.12/0.29/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to SDVSD.COM[69.43.161.181]: Connection refused)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12705]: 7FBDF1E4000B: to=<rickiricki@bellsouth.net>, relay=gateway-f1.isp.att.net[204.127.217.16]:25, delay=365145, delays=365144/0.66/0.3/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host gateway-f1.isp.att.net[204.127.217.16] refused to talk to me: 550-66.194.252.172 blocked by ldap:ou=rblmx,dc=att,dc=net 550 Error - Blocked for abuse. See http://att.net/blocks)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12708]: 716921E40074: to=<wtp302@aliveandkicking.com>, relay=none, delay=332562, delays=332561/0.67/0.11/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to aliveandkicking.com[72.13.32.43]: No route to host)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12641]: D672B2213CCC: to=<docterpimp@kasan.com>, relay=none, delay=426987, delays=426987/0.15/0.29/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to kasan.com[176.74.176.178]: Connection refused)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12691]: 4898C2213D2C: to=<boulanger.l@synpatico.ca>, relay=none, delay=253044, delays=253043/0.55/0.15/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to synpatico.ca[216.40.47.17]: Connection refused)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12674]: C57712213B52: to=<rubis_29@lives.ca>, relay=none, delay=105486, delays=105486/0.41/0.29/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to lives.ca[176.74.176.178]: Connection refused)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12705]: 7FBDF1E4000B: to=<rickjames.8@bellsouth.net>, relay=gateway-f1.isp.att.net[204.127.217.16]:25, delay=365145, delays=365144/0.66/0.3/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host gateway-f1.isp.att.net[204.127.217.16] refused to talk to me: 550-66.194.252.172 blocked by ldap:ou=rblmx,dc=att,dc=net 550 Error - Blocked for abuse. See http://att.net/blocks)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12705]: 7FBDF1E4000B: to=<rickm269@bellsouth.net>, relay=gateway-f1.isp.att.net[204.127.217.16]:25, delay=365145, delays=365144/0.66/0.3/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host gateway-f1.isp.att.net[204.127.217.16] refused to talk to me: 550-66.194.252.172 blocked by ldap:ou=rblmx,dc=att,dc=net 550 Error - Blocked for abuse. See http://att.net/blocks)
Nov 18 23:59:13 mail postfix/smtp[12669]: C25832213D2F: to=<mfrance2004@homtail.com>, relay=none, delay=339796, delays=339793/0.37/2.7/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=homtail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:14 mail postfix/smtp[12698]: 773272213C6C: lost connection with mx1.cofely-gdfsuez.com[83.137.242.245] while receiving the initial server greeting
Nov 18 23:59:14 mail postfix/smtp[12656]: BEB7A2213CA9: to=<steeve@solutionweb.ca>, relay=none, delay=391163, delays=391159/0.25/3.3/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=solutionweb.ca type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:14 mail postfix/smtp[12680]: C57712213B52: to=<www.francois@moncourrier.com>, relay=none, delay=105489, delays=105486/0.46/3.1/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncourrier.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:14 mail postfix/smtp[12662]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<johann_jenny@moncourrier.com>, relay=none, delay=65176, delays=65173/0.31/3.3/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncourrier.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:14 mail postfix/smtp[12662]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<poulinb@moncourrier.com>, relay=none, delay=65176, delays=65173/0.31/3.3/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncourrier.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12660]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<rambo4400@monarch.net>, relay=none, delay=65177, delays=65173/0.29/4.6/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=monarch.net type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12631]: 9F7B92213D22: to=<kathy.d@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=341889, delays=341884/0.07/5/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12689]: 4898C2213D2C: to=<denisebrandt@sympatico.net>, relay=none, delay=253048, delays=253043/0.53/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=sympatico.net type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12699]: 773272213C6C: to=<archedenoemie@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=70297, delays=70292/0.62/4.5/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12679]: C57712213B52: to=<cofeeboy@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=105491, delays=105486/0.45/4.7/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12679]: C57712213B52: to=<jmroy@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=105491, delays=105486/0.45/4.7/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12631]: 9F7B92213D22: to=<th@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=341889, delays=341884/0.07/5/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12699]: 773272213C6C: to=<bruno.lec@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=70297, delays=70292/0.62/4.5/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12679]: C57712213B52: to=<jvmelancon@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=105491, delays=105486/0.45/4.7/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12699]: 773272213C6C: to=<daniel_l@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=70297, delays=70292/0.62/4.5/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12699]: 773272213C6C: to=<davebond@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=70297, delays=70292/0.62/4.5/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12699]: 773272213C6C: to=<lysan@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=70297, delays=70292/0.62/4.5/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12699]: 773272213C6C: to=<smoltz@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=70297, delays=70292/0.62/4.5/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12699]: 773272213C6C: to=<yawnick@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=70297, delays=70292/0.62/4.5/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:16 mail postfix/smtp[12676]: C57712213B52: to=<stephen@metropolitainsuzuki.com>, relay=none, delay=105491, delays=105486/0.43/5.4/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=metropolitainsuzuki.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:17 mail postfix/smtp[12661]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<_mirage_@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=65178, delays=65173/0.3/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:17 mail postfix/smtp[12661]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<alouf@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=65178, delays=65173/0.3/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:17 mail postfix/smtp[12661]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<hulin@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=65178, delays=65173/0.3/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:17 mail postfix/smtp[12661]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<keven36@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=65178, delays=65173/0.3/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:17 mail postfix/smtp[12661]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<larokandroll@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=65178, delays=65173/0.3/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:17 mail postfix/smtp[12661]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<mick_chatter@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=65178, delays=65173/0.3/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:17 mail postfix/smtp[12661]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<scorpion_21@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=65178, delays=65173/0.3/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:17 mail postfix/smtp[12661]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<so_b@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=65178, delays=65173/0.3/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:17 mail postfix/smtp[12661]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<soleil@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=65178, delays=65173/0.3/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:17 mail postfix/smtp[12661]: BBDC12213C6F: to=<yan@moncanoe.com>, relay=none, delay=65178, delays=65173/0.3/4.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=moncanoe.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:19 mail postfix/smtp[12659]: B4E252213CFC: to=<dcruzx84@hotmail.co>, relay=none, delay=396390, delays=396382/0.28/7.8/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=hotmail.co type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:23 mail postfix/smtp[12693]: 44E2C2213CD9: to=<DaveMitchell@pdsb.com>, relay=none, delay=425692, delays=425679/0.57/12/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=pdsb.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m115@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 450 4.7.1 Error: too many recipients from 66.194.252.172 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m116@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 450 4.7.1 Error: too many recipients from 66.194.252.172 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m117@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 450 4.7.1 Error: too many recipients from 66.194.252.172 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m118@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 450 4.7.1 Error: too many recipients from 66.194.252.172 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m119@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 450 4.7.1 Error: too many recipients from 66.194.252.172 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m120@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 450 4.7.1 Error: too many recipients from 66.194.252.172 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m121@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 450 4.7.1 Error: too many recipients from 66.194.252.172 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m123@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 450 4.7.1 Error: too many recipients from 66.194.252.172 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m124@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 450 4.7.1 Error: too many recipients from 66.194.252.172 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m125@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 450 4.7.1 Error: too many recipients from 66.194.252.172 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m126@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] said: 421 4.7.0 mail.zadarma.com Error: too many errors (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m110@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] while sending RCPT TO)
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m111@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] while sending RCPT TO)
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m112@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] while sending RCPT TO)
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m113@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] while sending RCPT TO)
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m114@zadarma.com>, relay=mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25]:25, delay=420854, delays=420841/0.6/1.3/11, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mail.zadarma.com[5.9.108.25] while sending RCPT TO)
Nov 18 23:59:24 mail postfix/smtp[12697]: 7B9112213CF4: to=<andgor3m127@zadarma
```

Comment: Where did the mail come in from? The relevant parts of your logs seem to be missing.

Comment: Even if you have deleted the account, that doesn't stop root from composing and submitting messages with that address set as the from address.  I would guess that maybe your system is compromised, or your web site has a bug of some sort that is permitting a privileged account submit mail.  Looking at your mail logs will tell you the effect of what is going on.  What you need to do is find out the cause, which might require you look at your access logs at the same time frame.  If you you have a good firewall outside this server, you might want to do some logging on that.

Comment: Ok thanks all I will try logging some more information.

Answer (score 2):

In order to help answer this question, you need to post the full log for one of the offending messages.  To do that, grep the log on the message ID (the message ID is the hex number after the process name, in your log snippit, the first one is: 189042213CB4).

That will give you the full detail on Postfix's processing of the message.  The very first line of that output should end in "client=".  This is the IP address of where the message originated from.  If its an internal address, go check to see what's happening on that machine; if its an external address, you may have a relay issue; and finally, if its localhost, then as Zoredache suggested, your mail server may be compromised.